# Can't make regular expression with negative lookaheads work to fix unescaped quotes in JSON

Tags: regex, json, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I have some JSON code in the following format:

```
[
  { "abc ": "d ef", "g": "h i", "jk lm no": "pq", "r st": "uvw xyz" },
  { "!1 2": " 3", "4 ": "5 6 7", " 8 ": "9 abc", "def": "hi "NAME" jk" },
  ...
]
```

I need to add backslashes in front of quotes in "NAME" to be able to parse this JSON correctly. So I need the above string to look like this:

```
[
  { "abc ": "d ef", "g": "h i", "jk lm no": "pq", "r st": "uvw xyz" },
  { "!1 2": " 3", "4 ": "5 6 7", " 8 ": "9 abc", "def": "hi \"NAME\" jk" },
  ...
]
```

I tried using regex to replace `(?!({ |": |", ))"(?!( }|: "|, "))` with `'\\\\"'`, but I get:

```
[
  { \"abc ": \"d ef", \"g": \"h i", \"jk lm no": \"pq", \"r st": \"uvw xyz" },
  { \"!1 2": \" 3", \"4 ": \"5 6 7", \" 8 ": \"9 abc", \"def": \"hi \"NAME\" jk" },
  ...
]
```

Please help to write a correct regular expression.

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question, but can't you fix the source of the illegal JSON file?

Comment: If not, are there any limits on what the incorrectly quoted sections may contain? For example, what if there was `, "foo": ` instead of `NAME`?

Comment: I can't fix the source, I get it from other software. There are no limitations on what names and values of a JSON object may contain, however there is always one space after {, : and comma, and before }. So, everything outside quotes has a fixed structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<![{,:] )"(?![:,]| })
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/tJ2dG0

---

#### Discussion

Firstly, I assume that your regex flavor supports *lookbehind*.

Secondly, how did I find this regex you'd say ?
Often, when you build a regular expression, you either build it for matching what you want or you build it for matching what you don't want. I use the latter here.

This is the regex for matching valid double quotes:

```
(?<=[{,:] )"|"(?=[:,]| })
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Demo:** http://regex101.com/r/oX4uM5

As you can see in the demo, the regex (let's call it `R`) doesn't capture invalid quotes. So the regex we are looking for is its (particular) opposite (ie `!R`). *particular* because we'll take the opposite of the look(behind|ahead) but not the quote inside `R`.

So

- `(?<=...)` becomes `(?<!...)`
- `(?=...)` becomes `(?!...)`
- `"|"` (read it `" OR "`) becomes (`" AND "`) simply `"`

hence the final regex at the top of this answer.

Comment: I've got to ask, what tool did you use to get the graphical flows of the Regex?